# Find out whether textbox text didnt change for a second in mvvm pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Can anyone help me to find out whether my TextBox's text didn't change for one second or not in MVVM pattern (using WPF).

In my ViewModel, I have a property

```
public String SearchText
{
    get
    {
        return _searchString;
    }

    set
    {
        _searchString = value;
        _functionProvidersView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

where `_functionProvidersView` is of Type `ObservableCollection<FunctionProviderViewModel>`. I want that refresh to happen only if the text didn't change for one second.

I tried to solve that problem with `System.Threading` but that didn't do the trick, does anyone have a simple solution?

Edit: Based on that `SearchText` my Collection is filtered. And because my Filter mechanism is taking some time, I want the filtering only happen if a user didn't change the Textbox text (didn't type anything) for one second.

The TextBox Attribute `UpdateSourceTrigger` is set to `PropertyChanged`. I could set this to `LostFocus` but that's not exactly what I want...

Comment: Can you explain your  question in more detail?

Comment: one second starts from when? constructor of view model? load of view? or some other event?

Comment: so your trigger is one second after key press or text changed in the text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a [timer](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx&ei=-RWQU8n_O43M0AWI-IGIAQ&usg=AFQjCNGLlfBW6dQQsl82Lb3MkNquPBX8wQ&bvm=bv.68235269,d.d2k) to delay the refresh invocation:

```
public class MainVm
{
    System.Threading.Timer timer;

    private string searchText = string.Empty;
    public string SearchText
    {
        get { return searchText; }
        set
        {
            searchText = value;

            timer.Change(1000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite); //reset the timer
        }
    }

    public MainVm()
    {
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(RefreshView, 
                                           null, 
                                           System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite,
                                           System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void RefreshView(object state)
    {
        //Here you need to use the dispatcher because the callback is called
        //from a non-UI thread
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            _functionProvidersView.Refresh()
        );
    }
}
```

In this way the `RefreshView` method will called after 1 second you stopped typing

Comment: Thanks for your help. But theres a compilation error (at RefreshView method) which says: cannot convert lambda expression to 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type.

Answer (score 0):

you have to raise the event like `RaisePropertyChanged` like

```
public String SearchText
   {
    get
    {
        return _searchString;
    }

    set
    {
        _searchString = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("functionProvidersView");
    }
   }
```

Comment: I dont know how this should work? If I dont call Refresh() on _functionProvidersView, my Collection wont get filtered?!

Comment: when you called RaisePropertychanged Event it will called your FunctionProviders collection property and again setter getter happen

Comment: so you want me to call refresh in the setter or getter of my FunctionProviders collection? But still how does this fix my waiting problem? I'm sorry but I dont understand

Comment: ok let me clear when you want your FunctionProvides became refresh?

Comment: When the TextBox's text didnt change for one second

Answer (score 0):

**WPF approach**

- defined a storyboard on TextChanged event
- added a boolean animation with two frames false at 0 and true at 1 second (you can customize as per your need, perhaps bind to settings)

  ```
  <TextBox>
      <TextBox.Triggers>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.TextChanged" >
              <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                      <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="DataContext.TextChanged" >
                          <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False" />
                          <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="True"/>
                      </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
      </TextBox.Triggers>
  </TextBox>
  ```

this will trigger property change upon text change and will send value as true at 1 second

code for view model

- added a property in view model to trigger the refresh
- in OnChanged handler i'll perform my logic for refresh etc

  ```
  public bool TextChanged
  {
      get { return (bool)GetValue(TextChangedProperty); }
      set { SetValue(TextChangedProperty, value); }
  }

  // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TextChanged.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TextChangedProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("TextChanged", typeof(bool), typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(false,OnTextChanged));

  private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      if ((bool)e.NewValue)
      {
          //your logic after 1 second
          (d as ViewModel)._functionProvidersView.Refresh();
      }
  }
  ```

  in this approach you dont have to manage timer manually it will be handled by wpf

Comment: this looks great, although it has a few little problems e.g. i cannot call _functionProvidersView.Refresh in a static method. Also can you explain the TextChanged property a little, I dont quite understand the GetValue and SetValue methods and what parameters you want to pass to them.

Comment: i updated my answer to call the method _functionProvidersView.Refresh. Secondly this property TextChanged is a meadiator of state from the animation of textbox to the view model. In this case it will be fired two times after the text change occur with value as false at 0 sec and as true at 1 second. So when it is true it will act as a trigger point to perform your logic.

Comment: I already implemented Albertos solution and didnt try your fix, but thanks for your effort.